# Отваливается php-fpm

Tags: настройка, php-fpm, php7

Проблема заключается в том, что под минимальным нагрузочным тестом, сервер начинает возвращать 503 ошибку.
Статический файл `html` отрабатывает замечательно, а вот `php`-файл c `phpinfo()` внутри отрабатывает на `fail 87/100`

```
ab -n 100 -c 5 site.ru
```

**Debian 8**, **PHP 7.0.10-1~dotdeb+8.1**

В какую сторону копать, ниразу не ставил **php 7** как и **debian 8** в связке **nginx+php-fpm**

```
[php]
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
```

Пробовал и на сокетах и на tcp

Comment: Проверьте /var/log/nginx/error.log (или hostname.error.log) и посмотрите какая ошибка возвращается от fpm.

Comment: fpm сам ошибок не возвращает никаких, то есть там нет ничего подозрительного. nginx начинает отдавать 503 ошибку, но только при запросах к php, статику отдает нормально

Comment: включите debug log на nginx, он вам расскажет, кто (и, возможно, почему) генерирует 503

Comment: @Etki не совсем понял что я там должен увидеть

Comment: @Etki '2016/09/08 17:04:06 [debug] 2708#2708: *5 http fastcgi header: "Status: 503 Service Unavailable"'

Comment: напишите вывод команды free -m может банально память кончается?